# How to make Canvas take 100% of remaining space?

Tags: css, html, canvas

Similar to how [i want a `div` to take 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space), 100% width, or both. i want a `Canvas` to take 100% width and 100% height:

([Link to JsFiddle for your perusal](http://jsfiddle.net/mzNTV/6/))

**Markup:**

```
<div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#canvasContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
#myCanvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(canvas.width, 0);
ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
ctx.stroke();
```

Which results in something ***not*** taking 100% of browser window:

[image]

It works fine if you delete the `Canvas`:

[image]

Downside of that is then i don't have a `Canvas`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Ani A canvas that takes 100% of it's containing div. In the end we'll be converting a native CAD application to canvas. First step: create a canvas the size of the *"client docked*" div. Maybe i'm not sure what you're asking: i want the entire canvas to be visible on screen at once - no overflow that requires a scrollbar.

Answer (score 9):

### Sizing a canvas element

If you stretch the canvas using CSS you will stretch the poor canvas which has a default size of 300x150 pixels to the whole screen - imagine you had an image of that size and which you did the same to - will look pretty bad.

Canvas content can not be stretched using CSS (it acts as an image that way). You need to explicitly set the **pixel** size of the canvas.

This means you will need to get the size of the parent container and set it as a pixel value on the canvas:

First off, to get rid of scroll bars etc.adjust the CSS you have:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Now modify this rule:

```
#myCanvas {
    background-color: green;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Now reduce your markup to this only (if you want the canvas covering the whole sceeen you don't need a container other than the window):

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Now we can calculate size:

```
var canvas;

window.onload = window.onresize = function() {

    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;   
}
```

And that's it.

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/k8y3dw0g/)** (resize the window to see).

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks Ken. Works as a charm.

Answer (score 1):

you can position absolute with 0 everywere:

```
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Then just look in which element it is positionned, add `position: relative` to handle the block it covers. In your case probably: `#canvasContainer`, but maybe `body` if it's just for a single full screen.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue in the past. My solution for it was setting `overflow: hidden` on the `html`

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mzNTV/7/)

It gets rid of that little bit at the bottom, which if you inspect the pages is just a little bit extra, and not actually the height of the body. If anyone has some insight into what that is I am all ears.

Comment: That seems to simply hide the scrollbars in the browser; which starts to become a problem when other elements appear.

Answer (score 1):

Modified some of the examples here to get mine to work.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FT3pP/1/

JS:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    SizeBackground();
} );

function SizeBackground(){
    var canvas = $( "canvas#background" )[0];

    fitToContainer( canvas );
}

function fitToContainer( canvas ) {
    canvas.width = canvas.parentElement.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.parentElement.clientHeight;
}
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0; }

div .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }
div#pallette {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px; }

canvas#background {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: black; }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="pallette">
        <div class="container">
            <canvas id="background"></canvas>
            <canvas id="middleground"></canvas>
            <canvas id="foreground"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div id="stats"></div>
        <div id="chat"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Only includes i had:

```
<!-- Styles Sheets -->
<link href="Scripts/App.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
```